# failed to load main-class manifest attribute from abc.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, unix, jar, executable-jar

HI,

I have created a runnable .jar file using eclipse and compiled it with jdk1.4.2, i am able to run it perfectly on windows but whenever i run it on unix it says "failed to load main-class manifest attribute from abc.jar" Why is it so

Please help

Saurabh

Comment: Please post the manifest file. Then we can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I usually avoid executable jars. Assuming, we have a class `com.example.MyClass` that has has `main` method, then the "executable jar"'s manifest (myapp.jar) needs the line

```
Main-Class: com.example.MyClass
```

Then you can start the application like this

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Apart from some classpath annoyances, this is pretty similiar to

```
java -cp myapp.jar com.example.MyClass
```

The "annoyance": if run the application with the `-jar` option, the classpath **has** to be defined in the manifest - it will ignore any `CLASSPATH` entry or `-cp` attribute. So if you have dependencies, you'll have to copy and paste them from the manifests classpath attribute to the `-cp` attribute:

```
java -cp myapp.jar;<other libs> com.example.MyClass
```